# Stability analysis of hybrid discrete-continuous systems

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, continuous-signals, stability, state-space

I'm trying to derive the overall state-space system model for a hybrid system, in order to plot its eigenvalues.

The system is shown as follows:

[image]

Which is originally from this paper: Modeling and Sensitivity Study of Consensus
Algorithm-Based Distributed Hierarchical
Control for DC Microgrids.

The blue part is a discrete algorithm with sampling time of 0.1s. The red part is the control system in discrete-time with sampling time of 1e<sup>-4</sup>s. And the green part is the plant model which represents a DC microgrid with buck converters and loads, in continuous-time.

As described in this paper, following is the procedure to find the overall system dynamics:

1. Discretize the plant model  using zero-order-hold (ZOH) method
   with the same sampling time of control system (1e<sup>-4</sup>s).
2. Combine the model in step 1 and the control system model.
3. Discretize the combined model in step 2 with the same sampling time of the algorithm (0.1 s).
4. Finally, combine the model in step 3 with the algorithm model to get the overall system model.

The procedure is depicted as shown below:
[image]

The procedure seems to make sense, but the question is:

Given that the plant model and the control system model are now combined with a discretized system with sampling time of 0.1 s, and the fact that we lose some information in between sampling instants, is the final system model accurate?

- If yes, can you explain how to derive the system dynamics with different sampling times and time domains?
- If not, what is an alternative approach to find the overall system dynamics? Is there a way to do so without equalizing the sampling times?

Sorry if I'm making a mistake, I'm new to control theory.